# If $(z_n)=(x_n, y_n)$ and $A_x$ is the set of adherence points of $x_n$ then show that $A_z \not = A_x \times A_y$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

> Let $(E_1, d_1)$ and $(E_2,d_2)$ be metric spaces, and $(E,d)=(E_1,d_1) \times (E_2,d_2)$. Let $(z_n) = (x_n, y_n)$, and $A_x, A_y, A_z$ be the set of adherence points of the sequences respectively. Show one inclusion, and prove there might not always exist an equality.

I figured that $A_z \subset A_x \times A_y$, and that there might not be this equality: $A_z = A_x \times A_y$. I didn't have much trouble proving that $A_z \subset A_x \times A_y$, but I am having a hard time to show that there usually $A_x \times A_y \not = A_z$. I just wonder that maybe giving an example illustrating this situation would ne enough?

Comment: What if $x_n=y_n$ for all $n$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Then there would be an equality. But I have to prove that there doesn't always exist one.

Comment: I'll try again: what if $x_n=y_n$, and the sequence $(x_n)$ has more than one adherence point?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see what you mean! In that case, once again, $z_n$ wouldn't have the same adherence points!